# What is the proof of this procedure

Tags: calculus, reference-request

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote) wikipedia article describes the general procedure for finding the Asymptote of algebraic curves without mentioning any proof. I tried googling but it produced no relevant results. where can I get the proof??

Comment: Where is the connection with implicit functions in the wikipedia article? Maybe someone can help you if you are more specific.

Comment: @Karl sorry I typo